error: can not resolve symbol OpenIdConnectUserInfoProcessor
I am upgrading our project form dxp 7.2 to 7.4. In old version we were using interface

OpenIdConnectUserInfoProcessor

to map the user data.
In 7.4, I am getting that this Interface is not available. I have looked alot but didn't find anything related to this.
Any suggestion on how to resolve this would be helpful.

It appears that the OpenIdConnectUserInfoProcessorImpl which implemented OpenIdConnectUserInfoProcessor in 7.2 (and 7.3) was changed in 7.4 to be just a processor instead : OIDCUserInfoProcessor. Depending on your case, you can use a different approach to fix your issue like a serviceoverride on the userlocalservice. Could you elaborate on what you wish to achieve?

@KristofMols Thank you, I have found OIDCUserInfoProcessor and do the implementation in processUser function. Similarly, I have found that this AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil is not available in ga112 7.4 version. Do you have an idea, where I can find?

the AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil is still available in the latest version of Liferay as you can find here: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/session/AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.java

@KristofMols : I want to get OpenIdConnectProviderNames(), but in 7.4 OpenIdConnectProviderRegistry is not available. Can you help, how can I get it?
